# upgrading friends installed query Facebook v2.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently use an FQL query to get a list of friends that have installed my app :

@"SELECT uid, name, pic_big FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN "
    @"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )";

But in the Facebook update from v2 to v2.1 FQL is deprecated. I am aware you can use the graph api request : https://graph.facebook.com/{user id}/friends?fields=installed 
But also in the update to v2.2 ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading ) it mentions that the ?installed field has been removed.

Quote from link :

'The /me/permissions edge previously returned an installed pseudo-permission that would indicate that someone had installed an app. In v2.1 this permission has been removed, and instead apps should assume that when /me/permissions returns any data (and not an error) that the user has installed the app.'

How can I get a list of users that use my app using graph api? I'm aware that you could request all friends and then query each one for permissions to determine whether they  have installed the app or not, but it seems rather cumbersome to be a solution that Facebook would want people to implement. There's surely something I am missing?

Thank you very much for your time, it's much appreciated :) And I hope this helps anyone else who is in the same situation.

Comment: You don't need the install field. /me/friends will just return the friends that have the app installed

Comment: you can just store each user id in your database. no facebook api call needed for that, although you will also get user who deinstalled your app that way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, much appreciated! Thank you WizKid , i'll try that now :)

Comment: I just tried the /me/friends query, it returned all friends rather than just friends with the app installed.